# How do disable .net framework 3.5 on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-6

Is there are some ability to disable .net 3.5 on IIS 6 for asp.net site? I just have an application (.net 2.0) that has not working on server with .net 3.5, is throw :

> Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.
>
> *Description:* An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> *Exception Details:*
>   System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you post the entire actual exception, with stack trace?

Comment: You might want to post on ServerFault.com as it could be Machine issue not a framework issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post the complete exception. Also, is the failing application a .NET 3.5 application? There is no "disable" in IIS because .NET 3.5 uses the .NET 2.0 CLR, just like .NET 2.0 and 3.0 did. .NET 3.5 does install service packs.

Comment: Have added detailed info about exception. This application written with .net 2.0, is AspDotNetStorefront site.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to "disable" anything. Your application should still be running in a v2.0 AppPool.

Scott Hanselman's blog post [How to set an IIS Application or AppPool to use ASP.NET 3.5 rather than 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx) is sort of the reverse of what you're asking, but it should help explain the situation more clearly.

In particular:

> [web.config is] where your web site is
>   told what version of the compiler to
>   use, and the new supporting libraries.
>
> **This is where you tell ASP.NET to use .NET 3.5, not in IIS.** IIS
>   AppPools know about CLR versions, not
>   Framework and compiler versions, those
>   are set by the application.

So your application is still running on the .NET 2.0 CLR, even if you have .NET 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is quite an old topic, but I had this issue today and managed to resolve it by deleting some registry entries.

1. Open "Regedit" and look for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\Security\Policy\Extensions\NamedPermissionSets
2. Export the keys in case you break something, then you can restore the original configuration.
3. Within this key you will have a number of sub keys (I had 'Internet' and 'Intranet')
4. Look at the values in the subkeys and remove any Keys which refer to versions of .NET later than 2.0.5027

I suppose the alternative to this would be to register the appropriate library and/or classes in your web.config.

Hope this helps the OP or anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this any use for you, but I think you can declare the required runtime for your site in the web.config file. Check out this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2004/05/14/132022.aspx). By specifically declaring which version of the .NET framework you want your site to use, it might help.

```
<configuration> 
    <startup> 
         <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.5027"/> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```